# AngularJS Select OnChange result not reflected in attached model

Tags: angularjs

I have the following markup inside my directive:

```
<select class="form-control" 
ng-change="changeLanguage()" 
ng-model="selectedLanguage" 
ng-options='lang.key as lang.name for lang in languages'></select>
<p>{{selectedLanguage}}</p>
```

And my directive's controllers relevant part is this:

```
$scope.languages = [{
    name: "Java",
    key: "java",
}, {
    name: "C",
    key: "c",
}];

$scope.$watch("selectedLanguage", function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log("watch", newValue, oldValue);
});

$scope.changeLanguage = function() {
    console.log("language changed: " + $scope.selectedLanguage)
}
```

However, when I change it via UI, it is not reflected in the controller, but it is available in the UI, I see the selected value. I tried both $watch and onChange to see, but both of them don't work. What is wrong here?

Comment: Try to initialize selectedLanguage in your controller as `$scope.selectedLanguage="";`

Comment: @Jan I did it, it did not fix it

Comment: Maybe `selectedLanguage` is in a different scope.

Comment: Code is perfect. Works perfectly for me. Share a plunkr or jsFiddle if possible.

Comment: It is in a directive, would that be related?

Comment: if its a directive you must include the directive's name somewhere in the html , where have you done that?

Comment: I have created it http://plnkr.co/edit/6s4gR07pqSEtKGAUdQL1, but it is working perfectly on plunker, I am about to lose my mind, I wonder if it is related to any other things I have used, creating conflict.

Comment: probably yes, there must be something wrong with your other code as u noticed this part of code works well

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work fine for me.  Here is an example of it working with the code you provided.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.languages = [{
    name: "Java",
    key: "java",
  }, {
    name: "C",
    key: "c",
  }];

  $scope.$watch("selectedLanguage", function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log("watch", newValue, oldValue);
  });

  $scope.changeLanguage = function() {
    console.log("language changed: " + $scope.selectedLanguage)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <select class="form-control" ng-change="changeLanguage()" ng-model="selectedLanguage" ng-options='lang.key as lang.name for lang in languages'></select>
  <p>{{selectedLanguage}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Weird, maybe problem is not there? In pluncker it works

```
   (function() {

    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

        app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope',
        function($scope) {
          $scope.languages = [{
            name: "Java",
            key: "java",
          }, {
            name: "C",
            key: "c",
          }];

          $scope.$watch("selectedLanguage", function(newValue, oldValue) {
            console.log("watch", newValue, oldValue);
          });

          $scope.changeLanguage = function() {
            console.log("language changed: " + $scope.selectedLanguage)
          }
        }
      ]);
        })()
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NHrK7MqAyVYWH5bQcpuq?p=preview)